# Refreshing webform when database is externally updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, winforms

For experimental purposes i've made a ASP.net webform that writes to a database. Ive also made a windows form(c#) that writes to the same database. 
The webform displays the text in a gridview and the winform displays the text in a datagridview.

My question is: is it possible to refresh the windows form and webform when the database is updated by the other? And if so, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Consider the Observer Pattern.

Comment: Query Notifications http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx

Comment: You can Use SignalR !

Answer (score 1):

George has suggested one good approach in his comment.

For ASP.Net, you could use [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) to update the web page.

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that simplifies the process of adding real-time web functionality to your applications. Real-time web functionality is the ability to have server-side code push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available.

The traditional approach would involve "polling" by the desktop app, that is, making a request every few seconds to see if there is new information. This approach can be resource-intense. You can also do polling from a web page, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this to use two timer controls, one in the WinForm and the other on the WebForm.

And at desired intervals just rebind the dataset.

Rebind Data

```
grdWaiver.DataSource = dv  'Set the dataview to the DataGrid
grdWaiver.DataBind()
```

(In above I used a dataview as a datasource)

Comment: The problem with sigalR is that It won't work with any IIS older than IIS7 and also needs .NET framework 4.0 at minimum.